# Advanced startup options appear in blank (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

[image: Screenshot of advanced startup options]

As you can see in the picture, it shows only the icons, but not the text. This happens even if I navigate through each of the options.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you get here by searching for advanced startup options? What do you want to achieve? TO edit startup applications or behavior perhaps?

Comment: I got there by the command "shutdown -r -t 0 -o" and I want to start in safe mode